# Why is my styling being overwritten when adding a new React Component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a React component utilizing Material-UI called 'Profile', with custom CSS to create responsive font sizing like such:

```
let theme = createMuiTheme();

theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);

theme.typography.h1 = {
    fontSize: '5.35rem',
    '@media (min-width: 600px)':{
        fontSize: '3.0rem',
    },
    '@media (max-width: 600px)':{
        fontSize: '2.2rem'
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]:{
        fontSize: '5.35rem'
    }
}
```

The first few lines of the return are:

```
export default function Profile () {
        return (
            <div>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    <Grid container direction="row">
                        <Grid item className="profile">
```

When I include this component in my `index.js` file, it renders perfectly. However, once I add a new component called 'PublicWorks.js' as such:

```
  <React.StrictMode>
      <Header />
      <Profile />
      <PublicWorks />
  </React.StrictMode>,
```

the responsive styling no longer works. The code for PublicWorks is very simple, essentially just this (with appropriate closing brackets):

```
import React from 'react';
import {Grid, Typography, Accordion, AccordionSummary, AccordionDetails, ThemeProvider} from '@material-ui/core';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';

export default function PublicWorks () {

    return (
        <div>
            <Accordion>
                <AccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} >
                    <Typography>Project 1</Typography>
                </AccordionSummary>
                <AccordionDetails>
```

Is this overriding caused by the nature of MuiTheme operating at more of a global scale, or am I doing something else incorrectly? Should I be trying something like:

```
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvide theme={theme}>
      <Header />
      <Profile />
      <PublicWorks />
    </ThemeProvide>
  </React.StrictMode>,
```

in order to implement this correctly?

Comment: Could you show the code inside `PublicWorks.js`?

Comment: I've just updated the code. Apologies for the confusion

Comment: If you need your custom theme in Header, Profile an PublicWorks component the answer is Yes, you shoul put the themProvider in the App,js

Comment: And if I just want it in Profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you are having may be correlated with [this issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/4155).

Regardless, in general you would need to use the `ThemeProvider` as parent of your components since it uses React Context

> This component takes a theme property, and makes it available down the
> React tree thanks to the context. It should preferably be used at the
> root of your component tree.

Docs: https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#themeprovider

---

Regarding your comment `And if I just want it in Profile?`

You can use other solutions such as [`makeStyles`](https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/) for this if you opt to style that component separately